# Array not acknowledging elements as linked lists

Tags: java

I have a hashmap class set up like this with an add method to add new elements to the hashmap. The linkedlist method is defined at a separate part in the code with an add method that's working. The problem is is that it doesn't acknowledge the elements of the array as linked lists, it just acts as though they're objects and doesn't allow the use of the add or size method. I can't change the array type and the method thats supposed to declare each of the elements as linked lists doesn't do anything.

```
class MyGenericLinkedHashMap<T> {
    public Object[] arr;
    
    public MyGenericLinkedHashMap(int capacity) {
        arr = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public void add(T target) 
    {
        if(arr[hashCode(target.hashCode())] == null)
        {
            arr[hashCode(target.hashCode())] = new MyGenericLinkedList<T>();
        }
        
        arr[target.hashCode()].add(target);
    }
    
    public int getListSize(int index) {
        return arr[index].size();
    }
    
    public int hashCode(int hashcode) {
        return Math.abs(hashcode) % arr.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Why would you recreate something, which already exists and is within the standard?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: @maio290: that's not a linked hash map. It's just a hash map using a linked list as as collision management mechanism.

Comment: `arr` is of type `Object[]`. Therefore the compiler assumes that each element is of type `Object`. That's all it knows. Why would it give you access to anything that's not in `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is defined as `Object[]`, the compiler treats each of its elements as an instance of `Object`, whatever subclass they may have. This is because one could also assign other subclasses of `Object` to the array positions. In that case, a call to `size()` would fail, because it does not (necessarily) have that method:

```
Object[] array = new Object[ size ];
array[ 0 ] = new Dog(); // <-- this is legal, as Dog extends Object
array[ 1 ] = new Car(); // <-- as well
array[ 0 ].bark(); // does not compile, because...
array[ 1 ].bark(); // ...should then be legal too.
```

and I don't know many `Car`s that `bark()`.

Solution:
Usually one can narrow the array to the (largest super-)class that has method size, like so:

```
MyGenericLinkedList[] array = new MyGenericLinkedList[ size ];
```

Since you specified you can't change the type of the array, we need to downcast each element individually, like so:

```
((MyGenericLinkedList< T >) array[ index ]).add( item );
```

Note: This is an unchecked cast, since erasure removes the type parameter on runtime. However, this is also the case when we obtain the linked list from the `MyGenericLinkedList[]` array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm not allowed to change the array type, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @ButchHarper: arbitrary restrictions like this should be communicated as part of the question. Homework questions are not forbidden, but it's useful to be upfront about it. You can also cast the result of `arr[index]` to `MyGenericLinkedList<T>` (which happens to be an unchecked cast, which is another can of worms, but you can ignore that for now).

Comment: I did specify in the original post that I could not change it. I tried type casting it, it's now giving me the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "MyGenericLinkedList.add(Object)" because "<local2>" is null", do you know where that could have come from?

Comment: @ButchHarper Ah, I overlooked the part where you can't change the array type. In that case, you need to cast. I have modified my answer accordingly